# load extra routes in shared module for app

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have 3 modules:

- app module (the app: consumer)
- app  routing module (defines the routes of the app: consumer)
- shared library module: module used by different consumers (app module)

The app routing module defines the routes for the app.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // lazy feature module (routed module)
  { path: 'doc', loadChildren: '../doc/modules/doc.module#DocModule' },
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: '../test/modules/test.module#TestModule' },
  {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'doc',
     pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

The app module imports this app routing module.

Now I want to be able to inject extra routes in the shared library (like page not found).

I tried defining it like this.

```
const coreRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

];

And use the forChild method:

```
RouterModule.forChild(coreRoutes)
```

But the problem is that I can't navigate to the app routing routes anymore.
Everything is page not found...

Comment: Please post the code of the `app.module` so that we can see the import order.

Comment: Ok I understand now thanks to your comment. The order was wrong I was first importing the shared module before the app routing module.

Comment: Okay. Glad I could help..

Comment: Order of modules is important and the same applies to your routes,

Answer (score 1):

First we need to import the app routing module and only after that we have to import the shared module (the order matters).